# multiple dataframes from pandas to one excel sheet without deleting other sheets with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i have 2 dfs which i want to export to an existing excel file which already has three sheets. The two dfs should be in sheet "Sheet1" (a new sheet)

```py
    df = pd.read_excel("Data Set Finished.xlsx", sheet_name="Details")
    df2 = df.sum(axis=1)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Data Set Finished.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode ="a")
    
    
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False) 
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow= 1,startcol=12, index=False, header=False)
```

But i get this error: `Sheet 'Sheet1' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.`
i tried xlsxwriter instead of openpyxl but that just deletes the other sheets and apparently xlsxwriter doesnt have the append mode. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big fan of `xlwings` which is part of the anaconda distribution.  This allows you to interactively interact with EXCEL which is really handy for viewing `dataframes` ( eg `xl.view(df)` ).  It will also allow you to position output exactly where you want it, and you could format cells (eg make titles bold and a different colour) should you want.

You could try something like this, where file should reference the existing workbook (including file path).  Here I have assumed `Sheet1` already exists in the excel workbook.  If that is not the case, then add a sheet via `wb.sheets.add()`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xl

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/1990', periods=10, freq='Q'),
    'a': np.random.choice(range(100),10),
    'b': np.random.choice(range(100),10),
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='Q'),
    'c': np.random.choice(range(100),10),
    'd': np.random.choice(range(100),10),
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2010', periods=10, freq='Q'),
    'e': np.random.choice(range(100),10),
    'f': np.random.choice(range(100),10),
})


file = 'C:/Users/BRB/Book1.xlsx'

wb = xl.Book(file)
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

ws.range('A1').value = df1
ws.range('E1').value = df2
ws.range('A14').value = df3

wb.save()
wb.close()
```

And if you want to suppress the index, just include the option `options(index=False)` as follows:

```
ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df1
ws.range('E1').options(index=False).value = df2
ws.range('A14').options(index=False).value = df3
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I also use this code if sheet1 already exists and has some other data in it? so if I include my dataframe in sheet1 the old data wont delete..?

Comment: Correct.  Did that work for you?

Comment: Yes it did! But I now have another question: why is my excel file immediatly opening itself if I run my code? My error is then that the permission is denied bc the file open but it just open itself

Comment: The package opens excel by default.  You have options to keep it in the background.  You can close it (as per above) once you have finished writing to it.  What error are you getting?  The above worked for me without issue.